# The next music does not play

Tags: java, kotlin

Upon clicking the next button, the next music failed to play. Despite displaying the title of the next song, the music that continued was the previously clicked track.

**NowPlaying.kt
**
`class NowPlaying : Fragment() {

```
companion object{
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    lateinit var binding: FragmentNowPlayingBinding
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_now_playing, container, false)
    binding = FragmentNowPlayingBinding.bind(view)
    binding.root.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    binding.playBtnPA.setOnClickListener {
        if (PlayerActivity.isPlaying) pauseMusic() else playMusic()
    }
    binding.nextBtnPA.setOnClickListener {
        setSongPosition(increment = true)
        PlayerActivity.musicService!!.createMediaPlayer()
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.music).centerCrop())
            .into(binding.imageView)
        binding.songNamePA.text = PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].title
        playMusic()
    }
    return view
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(PlayerActivity.musicService != null){
        binding.root.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.songNamePA.isSelected = true
        Glide.with(requireContext())
            .load(PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].artUri)
            .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.music).centerCrop())
            .into(binding.imageView)
        binding.songNamePA.text = PlayerActivity.musicListPA[PlayerActivity.songPosition].title
        if(PlayerActivity.isPlaying) binding.playBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.pause)
        else binding.playBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.play)
    }
}

private fun playMusic(){
    PlayerActivity.musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.start()
    binding.playBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.pause)
    PlayerActivity.binding.nextBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.pause)
    PlayerActivity.isPlaying = true
}
private fun pauseMusic(){
    PlayerActivity.musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.pause()
    binding.playBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.play)
    PlayerActivity.binding.nextBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.play)
    PlayerActivity.isPlaying = false
}
```

}`

**PlayerActivity.kt**

`
class PlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ServiceConnection, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

```
companion object {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerBinding
    lateinit var musicListPA: ArrayList<Music>
    var songPosition: Int = 0
    var isPlaying: Boolean = false
    var musicService: MusicService? = null
    var repeat: Boolean = false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityPlayerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val intent = Intent(this, MusicService::class.java)
    bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    startService(intent)

    initializeLayout()
    binding.backkBtnPA.setOnClickListener { finish()}
    binding.playPauseBtnPA.setOnClickListener {
        if (isPlaying) pauseMusic()
        else playMusic()
    }

    binding.backBtnPA.setOnClickListener { prevNextSong(increment = false) }
    binding.nextBtnPA.setOnClickListener { prevNextSong(increment = true) }

    binding.seekBarPA.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (fromUser) musicService?.mediaPlayer?.seekTo(progress)
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
    })
    binding.repeatBtnPA.setOnClickListener {
        if (!repeat) {
            repeat = true
            binding.repeatBtnPA.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple))
        } else {
            repeat = false
            binding.repeatBtnPA.setColorFilter(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this,
                    R.color.pink_salmon
                )
            )
        }
    }
    binding.equalizerBtnPA.setOnClickListener {
        try {
            val EqIntent = Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL)
            EqIntent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.audioSessionId)
            EqIntent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, baseContext.packageName)
            EqIntent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_CONTENT_TYPE, AudioEffect.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            startActivityForResult(EqIntent, 13)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Equalizer feature not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    }
}

override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
    val binder = service as MusicService.MyBinder
    musicService = binder.currentService()
    createMediaPlayer()
    musicService?.seekBarSetup()
}

override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
    musicService = null
}

private fun setLayout() {
    Glide.with(this)
        .load(musicListPA[songPosition].artUri)
        .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.music).centerCrop())
        .into(binding.songImgPA)

    binding.songNamePA.text = musicListPA[songPosition].title
    if (repeat) binding.repeatBtnPA.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple))

}

private fun createMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        if (musicService?.mediaPlayer == null) musicService?.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        musicService?.mediaPlayer?.reset()
        musicService?.mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(musicListPA[songPosition].path)
        musicService?.mediaPlayer?.prepare()
        musicService?.mediaPlayer?.start()
        isPlaying = true
        binding.playPauseBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.pause)
        binding.tvSeekBarStart.text =
            formatDuration(musicService?.mediaPlayer?.currentPosition?.toLong() ?: 0)
        binding.tvSeekBarEnd.text =
            formatDuration(musicService?.mediaPlayer?.duration?.toLong() ?: 0)
        binding.seekBarPA.progress = 0
        binding.seekBarPA.max = musicService?.mediaPlayer?.duration ?: 0
        musicService!!.mediaPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return
    }
}

private fun initializeLayout() {
    songPosition = intent.getIntExtra("index", 0)
    when (intent.getStringExtra("class")) {
        "MusicAdapter" -> {
            musicListPA = ArrayList()
            musicListPA.addAll(Settings.MusicListMA)
            setLayout()
        }

        "Settings" -> {
            musicListPA = ArrayList()
            musicListPA.addAll(Settings.MusicListMA)
            musicListPA.shuffle()
            setLayout()
        }
    }
}

private fun playMusic() {
    binding.playPauseBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.pause)
    isPlaying = true
    musicService?.mediaPlayer?.start()
}

private fun pauseMusic() {
    binding.playPauseBtnPA.setIconResource(R.drawable.play)
    isPlaying = false
    musicService?.mediaPlayer?.pause()
}

private fun prevNextSong(increment: Boolean) {
    if (increment) {
        setSongPosition(increment = true)
        setLayout()
        createMediaPlayer()
    } else {
        setSongPosition(increment = false)
        setLayout()
        createMediaPlayer()
    }
}

private fun setSongPosition(increment: Boolean) {
    if (increment) {
        if (musicListPA.size - 1 == songPosition)
            songPosition = 0
        else ++songPosition
    } else {
        if (0 == songPosition)
            songPosition = musicListPA.size - 1
        else --songPosition
    }
}

override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
    if (repeat) {
        // If repeat is enabled, play the current song again
        createMediaPlayer()
    } else {
        // If repeat is not enabled, proceed to the next song
        setSongPosition(increment = true)
        createMediaPlayer()
        try {
            setLayout()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 13 || resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        return
}
```

}

`
I hope when the next button is clicked, the next music will also play.

Comment: Why are you creating a new media service every time the button is clicked?
PlayerActivity.musicService!!.createMediaPlayer() - that smells wrong.